# WPF bind to changing command

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, command

I have a button that should bind to to command of a View. The problem is that this command changes runtime (and initially it is null). My code looks like this:

MyViewModel.cs

```
public class MyViewModel INotifyPropertChanged
{
    ....
    private CommandStorage? _commandStorage;
    public CommandStorage? commandStorage
    {
       get => _commandStorage;
       set
       {
           _commandStorage == value;
           OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CommandStorage));
       }
    }
    public ICommand MyCommand => commandStorage?.MyStoredCommand;
    ......
 }
```

MyView.xaml:

```
<Button Command={Binding MyCommand}
```

What I face here is that MyCommand is sets once to null during initialization. And even after commandStorage changes new value is not set to MyCommand.

Comment: Add `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyCommand));`

Comment: Can the property `CommandStorage.MyStoredCommand` also change after the assignment to `CommandStorage`?

Comment: @Clemens yeah it would have worked, but it feels a little wrong, because command storage has several command, so it would be awkward to notify about all of them, when I already notify about changing the storage

Comment: How else should `{Binding MyCommand}` be notified that `MyCommand` has changed? You may hoever call `OnPropertyChanged(null)` to notify that all properties have changed.

Comment: Why not just bind the button like `Command="{Binding CommandStorage.MyStoredCommand}"` like @SirRufo mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to the `CommandStorage` property that you raise change notifications for and remove the superfluous `MyCommand` property:

```
<Button Command="{Binding CommandStorage.MyStoredCommand}" />
```

The binding engine cannot be supposed to know to refresh the value of the `MyCommand` property when you raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `CommandStorage` property.

The other option is to actually raise the event for the data-bound property in the setter of the other property:

```
public CommandStorage? commandStorage
{
    get => _commandStorage;
    set
    {
        _commandStorage == value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CommandStorage));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyCommand));
    }
}
```

I guess it's just a typo but in the code you have posted, the property is called **c**ommandStorage.